# Improving shortest route algorithm

Tags: path-finding, a-star

I have working A* algorithm, but I want to improve it. It finds the shortest path and everything appears as it should. The problem is that I want for route to keep distance (1 empty node or more) from non-walkable grid cells.

Any ideas how to solve this problem?

How it looks now:

[image]

What I want to do:

[image]

Comment: Why do the yellow dots not avoid the walls all the way along?

Comment: Sorry for not fully illustrated example. It should go till the end.

Comment: So how about this: when your A* algorithm needs to know whether a square is a wall, tell it that the square is a wall if the square has any wall neighbours.

Comment: The above would work until you had a gap with only 1 block width to get through, then it would assume that there is a wall there and no path could be found.

Comment: You could make your Dot think it is wider than it actually is (3x3 rather than 1x1), that would give basically give it padding, but may introduce collision detection problems with the walls.

Comment: Yes, I was assuming that the "keep one block away" rule could never be broken, even if that meant there was no path. If it can be broken if necessary, then the solution would be more complex.

Comment: Good ideas. Thanks for both of you. If you could post your suggestions as answers to my question, I would happily mark them as accepted. Of course if you want some reputation points for that.

Comment: If it can't come within 1 square of a wall, it can't ever reach the destination...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution 1:**
Make your dot think it is bigger than it actually is (3x3 instead of 1x1) then work out path based on edges of the 3x3 square. (May require collision detection code, also a bypass to allow it through 1 block size gaps.)

**Solution 2:**
Calculate path as normal with an additional check so move your block 1 space away from the wall if there is space to do so.